# how to remove list item with dynimically created button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a button in javascript attaching it to the list item, but I can't seem to remove it with the same button created.  here is what  I started with. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
//creating remove button works fine, problem is deleting the list item

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
  button.id = "close";
  button.appendChild(txt);
  item.appendChild(button);
  list.insertBefore(item, list.childNodes[0]);
}

// this is what I came up with but it does not work.
// I do get an error "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null."

  var close = document.getElementById('close')
  close.onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: Could you create a  fiddle?

Comment: Hi, hope this helps.  https://jsfiddle.net/alexpham23/33g6jdk1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7594zay3/1/
The `addEventListener` should be part of the `addItem` method.

```
 list.insertBefore(item, list.childNodes[0]);
 var close = document.getElementById('close')
 close.addEventListener("click", function(){
 var div = this.parentElement;
 div.style.display = 'none';
 });
}
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks so much!!